# Why mysqli prepare statement is not sanitising the data

Tags: php, database, mysqli

i am using this code

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$heading = $_POST['upd_head'];
$note =  $_POST['upd_text'];
$post_id = $_POST['up_post_id'];
$supd_head= "UPDATE posts SET heading= ?, note=? WHERE post_id=?";
$stmt_head= mysqli_stmt_init($db_conx);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_head, $supd_head)){
echo "sql is not ready";
 }
else{
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_head, "sss", $heading,$note,$post_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_head);
}

?>
```

when i give this input

```
<script>alert('hack');</script>
```

it saves as it is in the database and gives an alert message when i refresh page after updating data. Why its not sanitizing the data first? But i think there is no use of `mysqli_real_escape_string` when using prepare statement.

Comment: how are you echoing out the variable?

Comment: _“Why its not sanitizing the data first?”_ - because that’s absolutely not its job …? Its job is to make sure that whatever data you throw at it, it doesn’t cause a problem while inserting that data into the database. _“and gives an alert message when i refresh page after updating data”_ - that’s because you did not treat the data properly while _outputting_ it onto the page. The database has little to nothing to do with that.

Comment: thanku for ur answer now i have understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_prepare` is not made to prevent [Cross Site Scripting (XXS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

It all depends on how you display the data. The link above shows an example:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

A lot of information can be find on the [OWASP website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values)

Comment: but it saves data as it is in database <script>alert('hack');<script> . Is it safe??

Comment: Why should it _not_ be safe?

Comment: means it safe. actually i have not so much knowledge about sql injection that is why i thought any special char input can cause sql injection but using prepare statement i think it will be safe to remove mysqli_real_escape_string ?

Comment: @nitinverma Look, we're talking about database and the application. The database sees this as just text. It's not gonna interpret this as javascript. When you run the query and show the result in a php or html file, it will render it as javascript. At that point of time you're gonna need to encode it like my answer and the links say so.

Comment: it means no worry about sql injection when using mysqli prepare statement

Comment: @nitinverma Yes and the problem you're describing has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Comment: just curious to know how can i output data having special character as it is after sanitising using mysqli_real_escape_string ?